# What are the standard viewport sizes (heights and widths) on tablet browser like safari on newest iOS and chrome on newest Android?

Tags: viewport

As I want to make true to scale screenshots of a web application, I need to know the standard viewport resolutions.

http://viewportsizes.com/ is a great ressource for that, but it provides only the standard width. The height is very important for my screens.

Any ressource would be appreciated.